# AngularJS and separate model classes

Tags: angularjs

I plan to use AngularJS verion 1.latest. I'm new to this framework. Previously I was programming in mainly in PHP. I've studied https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

As far as I understood - there is no model stricte. Controller has `$scope` and this is the data layer for view.

Then I have troubles how to logically put data models into Angular application. Assume that data model represents computer: 1 mainboard with some properties, 1..* ram modules, 1..* processors, 1..* hard drives. Each device has its own properties. The data is fetched via RESTful API with several requests.

The data will be shared among few controllers.

How should all this be organized to preserve testability? I'd use Service for operations with REST.

Comment: I would start here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: This is totally vague question having 'zero' Logic. Buddy go and understand properly what AngularJs is about. Model is the real value of any data, $scope is double binding of 'JS' and 'View'. Controller is nothing but the glue between View and its real conceptual value as 'Model'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was talking to very experienced developer. He confirmed what I've studied by myself.

For storing data about PC I use a service (lets call it data-service). Data can be fetched by the same service or another one. Then data from data-service can be accessed in each controller and assigned to controller variables available in view (which should use controllerAs).

The guy also suggested to have as small data models as possible. It should be pure objects (can be nested) preferable without additional methods (opposite to classes from any backend) as they role is only to carry data. This sounds like truth in 90% of cases.